# Get top n occurences based on related table value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Orders (Id, OrderDate, CreatorId)` and a table `OrderLines (Id, OrderId, OwnerIdentity, ProductId, Amount)`

Scenario is as follows: Someone opens up an `Order` and other users can then place their product orders on that order. Those users are the `OwnerId` of `OrderLines`.

I need to retrieve the top 3 latest orders that a user has placed an order on and display all of his orders placed, to give him an insight in his personal recent orders.

So my end result would be something like

```
OrderId | ProductId | Amount
----------------------------
      1 |         1 |      2
      1 |         7 |      1
      1 |         2 |      5
      4 |         4 |      3
      4 |         1 |      2
      8 |         4 |      1
      8 |         9 |      2
```

Comment: What type of SQL? Or, do you want SQL-92 only?

Comment: Create a sql fiddle?

Comment: TSQL, since I am running on sql server (2014)

Comment: @Nensec Did my answer work for you?

Comment: How are those table related?  Do you have and TSQL?

Comment: @Frisbee Sorry, I thought it to be obvious that the `OrderLines.OrderId` relates to `Orders.Id` and yes, I am running sql server so it is TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select o.Id as OrderId, ol.ProductId, ol.Amount from Orders o 
inner join OrderLines ol 
on o.Id = ol.OrderId where o.Id in 
(Select top 3 OrderId from Orders where OwnerId = @OwnerId) 
Order By o.OrderDate desc
```

You can add date time column to OrderLines table to query latest personal orders and then update the code by moving "order by OrderDate desc" section to sub select query.

Comment: Running that query I'm getting all orders back, not just three of them http://i.imgur.com/KIlyALq.png

Comment: I think Orders table has no field such OwnerIdentity. I just updated the query like this. 

Select OrderId, ProductId,Amount from Orders inner join OrderLines on Orders.Id = OrderLines.OrderId
where Orders.Id in (Select top 3 OrderId from OrderLines where OwnerIdentity = @ownerId group by OrderId) order by Orders.Id

Comment: That is close to what I am trying to achieve. It is now just taking the wrong orders. It's grabbing the first 3, rather than the last 3.

Comment: Actually, adding in the OwnerIdentity column to the results show me multiple OwnerIdentity. I was expecting to only see the one I put in as @ownerid

Comment: Add order by clause to sub select query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT OL.OrderId, OL.ProductID, OL.Amount 
FROM OrderLines OL WHERE OL.OrderId IN 
(
  SELECT TOP 3 O.OrderID FROM orders O LEFT JOIN OrderLines OL2 
ON OL2.orderId=O.OrderID 
WHERE OL2.OwnerIdentity =...
ORDER BY O.OrderDate DESC
) AND WHERE OL.OwnerIdentity =...
```

Comment: This query only gave me back 1 OrderId and for different OwnerId too

Comment: Same result still. Only getting 1 OrderId and multiple OwnerIdentity back

Comment: I added it in the outer select `SELECT OL.OrderId, OL.ProductID, OL.Amount, OL.OwnerIdentity`

Comment: This means that there are multiple owners associated with same OrderID. If this is the case, then we need to add a where clause outside as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84559/discussion-between-dhruvjoshi-and-nensec).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
select OrderId,  ProductId, Amount 
       row_number() over (partition by OrderID order by Orders.OrderDate) as rn
 from  OrderLines 
 join  Orders 
   on  OrderLines.OrderId = Orders.Id
 where OwnerIdentity = x
) lskdfj
where rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ol.OrderId, ol.ProductId, ol.Amount,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY ol.OrderId ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC) rn 
    FROM OrderLines ol
    JOIN Orders o ON ol.OrderId = o.Id
    WHERE OwnerIdentity = @OwnerId
)
SELECT OrderId, ProductId, Amount
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn <= 3
```